# Salesforce for outlook error on sidepanelcontainer.apexp

Tags: salesforce-for-outlook, connect-for-outlook

need help in fixing this issue (Salesforce for Outlook). Getting this error when i click the email icon(To add the Email, click next to those records.) for the contact. In one Sandbox it is working fine but in another sandbox I am getting this error.

The value 'null' is not valid for operator '>' 
Error is in expression '{!IF(a.otherCount > 1, 'block', 'none')}' in component  in page sidepanelcontainer.apexp